# javascript/htmlDOM display element while hiding the others

Tags: javascript, simple-html-dom

So I have written this clickDisplay function that displays certain elements on click, it works fine, yes, but obviously I needed a feature that would hide all the other elements, because they are supposed to be displayed in the same field, so right now they kind stack on top of eachother
this is what I came up with, but it sorta doesn't work and I don't know why

```
const pages = ['watch','chars','seasons','songs']

    function clickHide(element){
        document.getElementById(element).style.display = 'none';
    }

    function clickDisplay(element){
        document.getElementById(element).style.display = 'block';
        for(let x = 0 ; x < pages.length ; x++){
            if (pages[x]!=element){clickHide(pages[x]);}
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it sounds like you solved your own problem, I started putting together code before you posted, so I'll throw it up here for you.  :)

```
const pages = ['watch', 'chars', 'seasons', 'songs']

function clickHide (el) {
  pages.forEach((pel) => {
    setElement(pel, pel === el ? 'none' : 'block')
  })
}

function setElement(el, attr) {
  document.getElementById(el).style.display = attr
}
```

with the html having this:

```
onclick="clickHide('watch')"  // or 'chars' 'seasons' or 'songs'
```

Comment: thanks, btw, is this the way this should be approached at all?

Comment: It depends on who's answering. Some will say "yes" and some will say "no." I think this would typically be the standard, if you're using vanilla js.

Answer (score 0):

Oh wait, I don't know why but this suddenly works now. I only changed the placeholder text and refreshed the page

But I'm sure that this still is a stupid solution